# Is it possible to include a constant variable in panel data?

Tags: econometrics, panel-data

I am trying to do an estimation on a panel data set. The main variable I am interested in varies over time. However, I want to add one variable measuring distance. This one will be constant over time.

Is this possible to do in a panel data set? If not, are there any work arounds?

Comment: If your goal is to control for distance, the fixed effect does that. It's just that the effect of distance is not separately identified from all the other time-invariant variables. But if distance is a nuisance parameter that is not of interest, why would you care?

Answer (score 1):

Using a panel data set to estimate a linear model

$$y_{it} = \mathbf x_{it}^\top\beta + u_{it},$$

some covariates $\mathbf x_{it}$ can be time constant and hence vary only across individuals $i$ such that $\mathbf x_{it}^{\top} = (\mathbf w_{it},\mathbf z_i)$ and the model can be written as

$$y_{it} = \mathbf w_{it}^\top\beta_1 + \mathbf z_i^\top \beta_2 + u_{it},$$

this does however exclude the use of individual specific fixed effects. So whether they can be included depends on the specific model.